# Not able to login to the server

Tags: linux

I am trying to login to the server as oracle , But the ssh session hangs at below, It is not responding to any keys. It stuck over here. I am installing the oracle database on another session.

Last login: Thu Feb  6 08:21:54 EST 2020 on pts/2

I am having the single core system, 4GB RAM , I am seeing load as 31 and having 2G swap space.

My questions:-

1.I am able to login as another user using ssh , however not able to login as oracle user.

2.I suspect there is some OS level limitation for oracle user  which is causing the system to hang.

Any idea what all the things needed to be checked further?

Comment: Run ssh verbose, check the log files on the server, check /etc/passwd. But why are you trying to login as a service user in the first place? Usually they are configured that an interactive login is disabled, and there is absolutely no reason to do so.

Comment: check `ssh -vv <user>@<ip>` output where it stuck and add it to question, check in audit logs if it have anything, In case of hung check dmesg or message logs. Also check if user having any restricted shell.